# NSMutableArray how specify the path

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, tweak

I'm searching for a way to populate a NSMutableArray with images that aren't in the Springboard.app (it is a tweak for iPhone)

If I write this:

```
for (int i=startImage; i<=35; i++){

    if ((i<10)){
        [images addObject[UIImage imageNamed[NSString stringWithFormat:@"logoFlareAnim_00%i",i]];
    }
    else {
        [images addObject[UIImage imageNamed[NSString stringWithFormat:@"logoFlareAnim_0%i",i]]];
    }

}
```

but I can't specify ...

Comment: This has ***nothing*** to do with NSMutableArray.

Comment: It is objective-c, what I can't figure out is the specify part.  Im assuming "images" is supposed to be his NSMutableArray.  What part isn't working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my code images Was an NSMutableArray my problem was : add images that are in a path not in the document folder of an iPhone App ... It was for a MobileSubstrate tweak and the solution was navigate in the filesystem with ../../ to go to the root and specify the path es: if i'm in /Library/MobileSubstrate I use ../../PathOfTheImage

Answer (score 0):

umm from my understanding is you need a way to populate an array with images that are not in the app... Well first you have to put your images in a folder usually a resource file in your ide assuming XCode... then your can do this

```
// unless start image is an integer u cant use this so
  int i = 0;
  UIImage *image1;  
image1 = [UIImage imageNamed: @"FOO"];
for(i=0; i<=35; i++){
 if(i<10){
 [ARRAY addObject:image1] // I would advise knowing the API of NSMutableArrays
  }
}
```

or you could do

```
 int i = 0;
  UIImage *image1;
for(i=0; i<=35; i++){
 if(i<10){
[array insertObject:img1 atIndex:i];
```

If you choose to insert an object at a index make sure that the index before the one your are trying to access is set other wise the index will be set to null and an error will be thrown.

```
  }else 
 [array insertObject :img2 atIndexi];
}
```

or this

```
int i = 0;
NSMutableArray *array;
array = [NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:35]
  UIImage *image1;
for(i=0; i<=[array count]; i++){
 if(i<10){
[array insertObject:img1 atIndex:i];
  }else 
 [array insertObject :img2 atIndexi];

}
}
```

Comment: Is not the solution In my code images Was an NSMutableArray my problem was : add images that are in a path not in the document folder ... It was for a tweak and the solution was navigate in the filesystem with ../../ to go to the root and specify the path